# Custom Class with unknown quantity and types of objects in json string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, jqgrid-asp.net

I have created the following public class `colModelClass` so I can deserialize the colModel string for my `jqgrid`

```
public class colModelClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string index { get; set; }
    public string jsonmap { get; set; }
    public bool editable { get; set; }
    public bool sortable { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public string align { get; set; }
    public bool hidden { get; set; }
    public string sorttype { get; set; }
    public string formatter { get; set; }
    public string formatoptions { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, `formatoptions` isn't a string.  It is a `json` object with an unlimited number of possible items.  Not only can it contain each standard `formatoptions` item that ships with `jqgrid`, but it can contain custom options as well.

Which `Type` do I use for `formatoptions` that will allow an object like this:

```
{ "srcformat": "m/d/Y", "newformat": "m/d/Y" }
```

or this

```
{ "decimalSeparator":".","thousandsSeparator":"," }
```

or any other number and combination of options (that won't require me to update my class if I add additional options)?

Or, how do I create a `formatoptionsClass` class that will accept any string, bool, int, etc so it can build the class dynamically?

Comment: hmm, now I feel silly.  I didn't even think to try that.

Comment: @csg works perfectly, thanks. If you put that as an answer, I will accept it since the question has to remain.

Comment: Could give an example how to use as object for formatoption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in comment - put it as Object.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the datatype as 'Object' for unknown types and especially for JSON object.